# android ViewBinder with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I would like to know if my solution using a ViewBinder is correct and suitable for my problem.

I have implememented a ContentProvider. The startactivity extends ListActivity and displays all the entries from a sqliteDB using my contentprovider. A Click on one of the entries in the listview starts another activity showing detailinformation about this entry:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // Arzneimittel wurde durch Klick ausgewählt --> Detailansicht anzeigen
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MedikamenteDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("_ID", id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the layout of the Detail-Activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_heading_statusinfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading_status_info"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/datalist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_PhZnr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_phznr"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_Znr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/znr"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_SName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/sname"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_OName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/oname"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV_DoLC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/dolc"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Detail - Activity Class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_medikamente_detail);

        _id = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getLong("_ID"));

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,               
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                null,
                mFromColumns, 
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0); 
        mCallbacks = this;

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.datalist);
        mAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder());
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, mCallbacks);
    }
```

Within the activity I implemented an inner class for die ViewBinder:

```
private class ViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if(view.getId() == R.id.txtV_PhZnr) {
                    TextView phznr = (TextView)view;
                    phznr.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

The binding works yet the data is bound to the listview. The other ViewElements stay empty. I can't really understand, why I set the Text of the view "R.id.txtV_PhZnr" and this text appears in the listview-element while the txtV_PhZnr stays empty.

Why do I need a listView-element. As this is a master-detail relationship, only one dataset can be shown in the detail view.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I need a listView-element.

No, you do not need one. You can just load the data from your content provider and bind it to the `TextView`s that you have defined (the ones with ids `txtV_xxx`). Do this in the `onLoadFinished()` method.

> I can't really understand, why I set the Text of the view "R.id.txtV_PhZnr" and this text appears in the listview-element while the txtV_PhZnr stays empty.

The `view` parameter passed to `setViewValue()` method of `ViewBinder` will only have one of the ids from the array of view ids that you instantiate the `SimpleCursorAdapter` with. In your case the `view` parameter will only have the id `android.R.id.text1` since the passed-in array contains only this view id. Thus the body of `if(view.getId() == R.id.txtV_PhZnr) {...}` will never get executed. Hence `txtV_PhZnr` stays empty.

`ViewBinder` is used only when you need to alter the binding of data to views based on some condition. As far as your case goes, there is neither a need for a `ListView` nor a `ViewBinder`.